# How to sideload json in Rabl

Tags: rabl

I'm trying to format some data for ember - so far I have this json for a user which contains a list of ids for a related object

```
 {"user":[{"id":1,"name":"Eveniet ","usertag_ids":[1,2]},}
```

I want to add a sibling node to user with the data of that related object ie.

```
     {"user":[{"id":1,"name":"Eveniet ","usertags":[1,2]}],
      "usertags":[{"id":1,"name":"Eveniet "..etc..}}
```

a User has_many usertags in the backend

Any ideas on this appreciated

Answer (score 0):

sideloading has been discussed in following issue in rabl, https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/427